# Select average if day occured and does not find a date from column

Tags: average, teradata, teradatasql

I have a table of exchange rates that contain a day and a value column, where the first one is the day of the exchange rate and the other has the value of that day. Then I have another table which has amount value of a KPI in euros, so I need to join these to columns to extract the amount value of the KPI in the currency of the exchange rate table, which is in reales (BRL).

The problem is that the exchange rate table has not all the values from each day. In other words, some days does not appear, which are Saturdays and Sundays. In order to solve that, what I need to do is find the average of the days occured (in the month) if that specific date is not appearing in the table. So for example, 11th of Feb 2023 (Saturday) I don´t have the value, so it calculates the average of the previous 10 days of the month. In the 18th Feb 2023 (saturday) it should have a different value from 11th Feb, because the average of the 17 previous days of the month is different from the average in the 10 previous day.

I reach this query

```
SELECT 
extract(day from ps.summary_date) as day_month, 
sum(Cast(GGR_Amt_EUR as decimal (19,8))) GGR_Amt_EUR,
sum(Cast(GGR_Amt_EUR*New_TC_BRL as decimal (19,8))) GGR_Amt_BRL,

CASE WHEN 

TipoBRL.Conversion_Rate Is Not NULL and Oreplace(Dim_Fx_Snapshot.to_curr_cd,'  ','') ='BRL'
THEN TipoBRL.Conversion_Rate 
ELSE
(Select 
Cast(AVG(CAST(conversion_rate as decimal(19,8))) as decimal (19,8))Conversion_Rate
From Dim_Fx_Snapshot
Where Oreplace(from_curr_cd,'  ','')='EUR' And Oreplace(to_curr_cd,'  ','') ='BRL' And Month(snapshot_date)=Month(Date-1) And Year (snapshot_date)=Year(Date-1)
And platform_cd=2
) 
END
AS New_TC_BRL
FROM  fd_player_summary ps
/**Tipo de cambio BRL*/
 Left Join
(
select 
distinct 
snapshot_date,
 CAST(conversion_rate as decimal(19,8)) Conversion_Rate
from Dim_Fx_Snapshot
where Oreplace(from_curr_cd,'  ','')='EUR' and Oreplace(to_curr_cd,'  ','') ='BRL' and Month(snapshot_date)=Month(Date-1) And Year (snapshot_date)=Year(Date-1)
and platform_cd=2 
) TipoBRL  on TipoBRL.snapshot_date=ps.summary_date
/**/


WHERE month(ps.summary_date) = month(date-1) and year(ps.summary_date) = year(date-1)

GROUP BY 
New_TC_BRL,
day_month
```

The problem is that in every day that do not exist in the table exchange rate (those Saturdays and Sundays) is giving me the same average value, as I show [in this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAtCL.png). So for example the 11th and 18th Feb have the same value. I know is a problem of the case when but I do not know how to fix it. I guess I need a moving average for those days, but no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might return the expected result without join:

```
coalesce(Conversion_Rate      -- use rate if exists
        ,avg(Conversion_Rate) -- otherwise moving average of the 
         over (partition by   -- current month
                   extract(year from snapshot_date)
                  ,extract(month from snapshot_date)
               order by snapshot_date
               rows unbounded preceding
              )
        )
```

This might return NULL if the first day(s) of a month are NULL.

Edit:

Calculate the exchange rate first using a calendar table (of course, use your own calendar table instead of sys_calendar) like this:

```
select 
     c.calendar_date
    ,coalesce(Conversion_Rate      -- use rate if exists
             ,avg(Conversion_Rate) -- otherwise moving average of the 
              over (partition by   -- current month
                       extract(year from c.calendar_date)
                      ,extract(month from c.calendar_date)
                    order by c.calendar_date
                    rows unbounded preceding
                   )
              ) New_TC_BRL
from sys_calendar.calendar as c
left join
 (
    select 
       distinct 
       snapshot_date,
       CAST(conversion_rate as decimal(19,8)) Conversion_Rate
    from Dim_Fx_Snapshot
    where Oreplace(from_curr_cd,'  ','')='EUR' and Oreplace(to_curr_cd,'  ','') ='BRL' and Month(snapshot_date)=Month(Date-1) And Year (snapshot_date)=Year(Date-1)
    and platform_cd=2 
 ) AS dt
on c.calendar_date = dt.snapshot_date
```

Btw, as historical exchange rates don't change, they should be calculated once daily and stored in a table. Your current approach doesn't seem to be efficient.

Comment: I don´t get it. But how can I join these two columns removing the join? How it will distribute correctly for each day? I tried to run this query separately alone and is not giving me values for saturday and sundays

Comment: Of course, you still need to join fd_player_summary to Dim_Fx_Snapshot, but you did it twice, a left join and a Scalar Subquery (and this is no longer needed). My query should replace the New_TC_BRL calculation, but without example data it's hard to say. I would suggest to left join Dim_Fx_Snapshot to a calendar table to get the missing dates and then apply my calculation. This result is then joined to fd_player_summary

Comment: Okk, got it. I replace New_TC_BRL with your query and is giving me "Order Analytical Functions can not be nested". I put my query in a different answer

Comment: You try to aggregate over he result of an OLAP function, which is not allowed (requires nesting)

Comment: the problem is that I don´t have a calendar date. The day I take it from transactional table, that has for every day, which is the fd_player_summary. But I guess I replace in your join by fd_player_summary

Comment: Why is there no calendar? It's a must in a DWH. You can use the built-in sys_calendar, but this is not a permanent substitue for your copmany calendar.

Comment: sorry, there is a calendar table, called dim_calendar (and date column call calendar_date), and I did not know until now. The query you wrote seems working. I tried it with 4,5,11 and 12 and is giving me the moving average numbers that I wanted. I really appreciate your help, thank you so much! You solved my problem!